# Two titleviews in dotnet maui

Tags: xaml, maui, titlebar

Im trying to create a Maui application with a dynamic Tabbar which should also be navigateable (and thus consist of NavigationPages). When I switch to a different tab, everything works fine, but as soon as is switch to an alreay visited tab, two titlebars appear:

[image]

One with the style i have defined (upper) and a default titlebar (lower). How can I remove the default titlebar?

Important code:

App.xaml.cs:

`MainPage = new NavigationPage(new AppShell());`

Page1:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:foo"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:foo.Converters"
             x:Class="foo.MainPage"
             NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"
             Title="foo"
             Loaded="ContentPage_Loaded">

    -- Content --
    
</ContentPage>
```

Page2:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="foo.Views.fooPage"
             Title="foo">

        -- Content --

</ContentPage>
```

NavigationbarStyle:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="foo.Resources.Styles.NavigationbarStyle">

    <Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
        <Setter Property="BarBackground" Value="{DynamicResource NavigationBarBackgroundColor}"/>
        <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="White"/>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

AppShell (more tabs are added later on):

```
<Shell
    x:Class="foo.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:foo"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:foo.Views"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">

    <TabBar x:Name="MainTabBar">
        <ShellContent Title="Home"
                      Icon="alert_icon_2_neg.png"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:StartPage}">
            
        </ShellContent>
    </TabBar>

</Shell>
```

Comment: I don't think you should use an `AppShell` inside a `NavigationPage`, you have to choose one of them. What you have there is the title view of both of them, you should check how to do everything with shell (or with NavigationPage if you want to really customize everything).

Comment: You can remove the title of the page in the page1 or page2.